# JPA/Hibernate @MappedSuperclass and @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, mappedsuperclass

I have 3 tables represented by JPA model.
The first one:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Boolean active;  
}
```

Next class extends BaseEntity:

```
 @Entity
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
 public abstract class Person extends BaseEntity{
    private String name;
 }
```

The last one is Student which extends Person:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Student extends Person{
    private Integer grade;
}
```

So, I have field "active" both in Person and Student tables. I want that when I update field "active" through PersonRepository it also updates appropriate row in Student table. For now it updates only Person table.
Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate "active" across two tables ? Do you have a concrete class that extend student ?

Comment: Column `active` in `Student` table shouldn't exists. Did you create this yourself, or it was generated by Hibernate?

Comment: @Predrag Maric Actually it exists because of MappedSuperclass.

Comment: @M4ver1k I want to have ability to filter Persons and Students by "active" field. But when I update "active" in Person table, Student is not updated. That's why I have discrepancy between these tables.

Comment: @YuriyGorbylov Ok got it, I would not keep Person and Student as separate tables in DB, but again it would depend on your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution with annotation @Formula:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Student extends Person{

    @Formula("(SELECT p.active FROM person p WHERE p.id = id)")
    private Boolean active;
    private Integer grade;
}
```

And implemented method which updates "active" field in Person table instead of Student (I use Spring Data):

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{

    @Override
    @Query("update Person p set p.active = false where p.id = ?1")
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void deactivate(Long id);
}
```

@Formula will take the "active" value of Person and insert into Student with the same id. Eventually, "active" field of Student won't be used at all, but I can't get rid of it because of @MappedSuperclass.